# GetDirectories - Find the directory that does not match the pattern

Tags: c#, getdirectories

I have 140 directories that I'm trying to process.  According to my tests there are 139 directories that match my file pattern (*abc.txt).

I'm trying to find the 1 directory to verify that in fact it does not have a *abc.txt in it.

How can I do this?

The following code gives me the 140 directories number:

```cs
var directoryCount = from subdirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(paramStartFilePath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                     where Directory.GetDirectories(subdirectory).Length == 0
                     select subdirectory;
```

I'm gathering the files based off the pattern like this:

```cs
dirInfoFiles= new DirectoryInfo(startFilePath);

IEnumerable<FileInfo> listFiles = dirInfoFiles.EnumerateFiles("*abc.txt, System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

How can I find the the one directory that doesn't contain my .txt file?

Answer (score 2):

There is always the running the tank through the village approach: just enumerate `*.*` and then exclude the patterns that don't match.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all directories that does not contain at least one txt-file which name ends with "abc":

```
IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> matchingDirs = dirInfoFiles.EnumerateDirectories("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
   .Where(d => !d.EnumerateFiles().Any(f => f.Extension.ToUpper() == ".TXT" 
           && f.Name.EndsWith("abc", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

or the same in other words, possibly more readable:

```
IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> matchingDirs = dirInfoFiles
    .EnumerateDirectories("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(d => !d.EnumerateFiles("*abc.txt").Any());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take. It returns the first item (or null) that contains a file ending with the text you are looking for and is case insensitive. You could remove the lambdas to make it more readable.

```
 var directory = Directory.GetDirectories((paramStartFilePath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => new DirectoryInfo(x).EnumerateFiles().Any(f => !f.Name.EndsWith("abc.txt",true,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)));
```